# Failed to delete profile from underlying stores in commerce server 2007

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

While invoking the "DeleteProfile" method of the "ProfileContext" option for a Contact record. I'm getting the following error:

Failed to delete profile from underlying stores
Please check key or values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the contact record key was the u_user_id column and I was attempting to delete by the u_contact_id field. So i just had the wrong key.